# C# Excel Interop row limit -> HRESULT: 0x800A03EC exception thrown

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I have a C# application which purpose is to store a big amount of data. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll Version 14.0.0.0) to help me accomplish this. I have Excel 2007 installed.

I use the following lines:

```
    excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);//*--------> LINE NOT WORKING */
    excelWorksheetBeingWritten = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

My code then iterates through a big list of objects, and each time a row must be written I do something like:

```
    var startCell = excelWorksheetBeingWritten.Cells[excelLineCounter, 1];
    var endCell = excelWorksheetBeingWritten.Cells[excelLineCounter, 2];
    string[] tmpArray = new string[2] { stringVar1, stringVar2 };
    tmpRange = excelWorksheetBeingWritten.Range[startCell, endCell];
    tmpRange.Value = tmpArray;
```

When excelLineCounter exceeds 65536, the "HRESULT: 0x800A03EC exception" is thrown. I am perfectly aware of the (in)famous pre-Excel2007 row limit (which is precisely 65536). What I don't understand is why the interops are using that limit, when Excel 2007 (my version) has a documented limit of 1.048.576 rows.

On the other hand, if I replace the above "LINE NOT WORKING" by the following, it seems to use the Excel 2007 row limit, and the exception vanishes:

`excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"H:\Workbook1.xlsx");//*--------> LINE WORKING */`

Note: "Workbook1.xlsx" is an empty workbook previously saved as "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)"

Can someone please tell me what kind of sorcery do I need to do in order to configure the Excel Interop objects to use the Excel 2007 limits by default, preferably without having a previously saved empty .xlsx file laying around?

Comment: Is it necessary you want to generate Excel file.. You can generate .csv file that would be much more easier to handle. You can avoid Row limit in Excel.

Comment: Are you using file .xls? If so may be that your problem.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use Interop (e.g. an Excel Add-in and you're doing this interactively), then I'd strongly suggest you don't create Excel files this way. It's very slow & [not supported in some scenarios](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). Something in managed code like [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) might be a better fit.

Comment: user3501749 -> Yes, the request is to generate at least one .XLSX file at the end. The strategy for when the row count reaches the aforementioned Excel 2007 row limit is to flush the data to one file and start writing into another.
M. A. Cordeiro -> I didn's understand your question. I don't want to use a file to start with, I am building a new one from scratch. I used the "Workbook1.xlsx" file on the example to tell you that, by opening the workbook from an existing XLSX file, the limit applied is the 1.048.576 rows limit, and not the 65536 rows limit used on the "LINE NOT WORKING".

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue yesterday and the solution is to change your Excel settings to create xlsx files by default.

In Excel: File -> Options -> Save -> Save files in this format

Your default is probably 'Excel 97-2003 (*.xls)' like mine was.  If you change it to 'Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)', your code will work.